# issue with nextjs build. ReferenceErrror: window is not defined

Tags: typescript, firebase, next.js, build, referenceerror

I am trying to build my app, but I cannot figure out why this `ReferenceError: window is not defined` should be occurring especially since I am using 'use client'

```
"use client";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { ref, getDownloadURL } from "firebase/storage";
import { storage } from "./firebase"; // Adjust the import path as needed
import Image from "next/image";

const Hero = () => {
    const [bgImageUrl, setBgImageUrl] = useState("");

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchImage = async () => {
            const storageRef = ref(storage, "/Hero.jpg"); // Update path accordingly
            try {
                const url = await getDownloadURL(storageRef);
                setBgImageUrl(url);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Error fetching image from Firebase:", error);
            }
        };

        fetchImage();
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            {bgImageUrl && (
                <Image src={bgImageUrl} alt="Hero Image" fill={true} />
            )}
        </>
    );
};

export default Hero;
```

I have commented out all components until I had just one component with the issue. this component is displayed on my homepage. The image renders locally. The build fails.

> ReferenceError: window is not defined
> at /home/cjbellmyer/code/green_country/.next/server/app/page.js:512:5749
> at 4860 (/home/cjbellmyer/code/green_country/.next/server/app/page.js:512:16127)
> at t (/home/cjbellmyer/code/green_country/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:1:127)
> at 7586 (/home/cjbellmyer/code/green_country/.next/server/app/page.js:848:47)
> at t (/home/cjbellmyer/code/green_country/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:1:127)
> at 9165 (/home/cjbellmyer/code/green_country/.next/server/app/page.js:512:2954)
> at t (/home/cjbellmyer/code/green_country/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:1:127)
> at F (/home/cjbellmyer/code/green_country/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:94693)
> at j (/home/cjbellmyer/code/green_country/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:93244)
> at rP (/home/cjbellmyer/code/green_country/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:33905)
> Generating static pages (4/4)
>
> Export encountered errors on following paths:
> /page: /

I have tried setting a default path in my `useState`. I have tried using a regular `img` tag instead of Image component.

Answer (score 0):

It **should** work but doesn't. Why?

First you need to understand why reference error happens.

It can happen for many different reasons but most common are when you are trying to use something before it's defined or that it doesn't exist or not available in the current scope.

Now, while 'use client' indicates that specific component be run client side, it doesn't inherently solve issues compatibility with certain client side code.

That includes browser API's like **window** and **document**.

But I'm not calling anything like that, in-fact there's not even a  mention of **window** here. So why is it giving the reference error?

You are not using the **window** but firebase does. Hence, the window reference error.

You can resolve this by ensuring that code accessing firebase is only used in client context. To do this, just check if **window** is available.

```
const fetchImage = async () => {
    // Add this check
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        const storageRef = ref(storage, "/Hero.jpg"); // Update path accordingly
        try {
            const url = await getDownloadURL(storageRef);
            setBgImageUrl(url);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error fetching image from Firebase:", error);
        }
    }
};
```